# Is it possible to use SUMIFS or SUMIF with data broken out into multiple lines per cell

Tags: split, flatten, sumifs

[Example Data and Wanted Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK1Kq.jpg)

I have two columns, 1 containing SKUs and the next containing quantity of each sku but each cell can contain multiple rows with each row containing a different sku and the respective quantity in the corresponding column and row.

Esentially I want to force google sheets to treat each new line as if it was was in it's own cell and use SUMIFS or SUMIF as I normally would.

I need to do a 1 cell look up for each SKU that reflects the total quantity without needing reformat the data in a new sheet.

This is possible if you reformat the data into a new sheet using the lines below and then SUMIF/SUMIFS
=flatten(arrayformula(split(B4:B9,char(10))))
=flatten(arrayformula(split(C4:C9,char(10))))

I tried putting this all into the SUMIFS
=sumifs(flatten(arrayformula(split(D4:D9,char(10)))),flatten(arrayformula(split(C4:C9,char(10)))),"=*"&R4&"*")
but get that the argument must be a range.

Trying with SUMIF
=sumif(flatten(arrayformula(split(B4:B9,char(10)))),R12,flatten(arrayformula(split(C4:C9,char(10)))))
I get that the argument must be a range?

Is this possible?  Other ideas to do it without putting the data into a new sheet.